# Set Correct Username for Audit.NET logs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, audit.net

I am setting up Audit.NET using the below configuration

```
Configuration.Setup()
.UseEntityFramework(_ => _
    .AuditTypeMapper(t => typeof(AuditLog))
    .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((ev, entry, entity) =>
    {
        entity.AuditData = entry.ToJson();
        entity.TableName = entry.EntityType.Name;
        entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        entity.CreatedBy = Environment.UserName;
        entity.TablePK = entry.PrimaryKey.First().Value.ToString();
    })
.IgnoreMatchedProperties(true));
```

However here Environment.UserName is giving windows user name and not the logged in username.

Elsewhere in the application I am able to get the logged in user name like

```
User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)
```

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways this can be accomplished, but ultimately it will depend on your specific use case.

If you can't (or don't want to) change your `DbContext`, you can have a [custom action](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/README.md#custom-actions) to resolve the HTTP context accessor from the DbContext.

For example, in your `program.cs`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Create the custom action to override the UserName 
Audit.Core.Configuration.AddOnCreatedAction(scope =>
{
    // Get the HTTP context accessor
    var ctxAccessor = scope.GetEntityFrameworkEvent().GetDbContext().GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    // Get the user name
    var userName = ctxAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
    // Override the environment's user name 
    scope.Event.Environment.UserName = userName;
    // Or set a custom field with it
    scope.SetCustomField("UserName", userName);
});

app.Run();
```

Another way, assuming your audited `DbContext` inherits from `AuditDbContext`, is to Inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` to your `DbContext` constructor (or use the GetService extension method) to retrieve the user and set a [custom audit field](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#custom-fields) with the username.

For example:

```cs
public class YourDbContext : AuditDbContext
{
    public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(options)
    {
        var user = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);

        this.AddAuditCustomField("UserName", user);
    }
    // ...
}
```

or just:

```cs
public class YourDbContext : AuditDbContext
{
    public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        var ctxAccessor = this.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var user = ctxAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);

        this.AddAuditCustomField("UserName", user);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thnx, I used your third code, and got error Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.get returned null.

in the var user line..